# Issue with all sliders and slideshow in my javascript innerHTML

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow

I have an issue which block me.

I want a slider/slideshow in my HTML generated page with javascript.
In my web application I have 2 steps:
- a div with a form
- a div with results

When i click on my "ok" button, first div is not shown and second div is displayed (it's ok).
Depending on the results, i want to display on my second div a slider / slideshow with severals images.

I have found severals jquery sliseshow, tested them in a simple html page it's worked, 
but when I put them in my javascript code which generate the div element, then slider is not displayed!

sample of my code:

- works at the end of the page in the HTML side:

  Slider :

it's working

but when i put it in the javascript, it's not displayed!!!

```
result_html += "<div class='slider-wrapper theme-default'><div id='imgslider' class='nivoSlider'><img src='nivo-slider/demo/images/toystory.jpg' alt='' data-transition='slideInLeft'><img src='nivo-slider/demo/images/up.jpg' alt='' data-transition='slideInLeft'><img src='nivo-slider/demo/images/walle.jpg' alt='' data-transition='slideInLeft'><img src='nivo-slider/demo/images/nemo.jpg' alt='' data-transition='slideInLeft'></div></div>";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result_html;
```

I have tested with severals slideshow, so have you some ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you binding the slider behavior to the slider div? If you are using $('.slider-wrapper').each(function() { ...do slider... }); then that is your problem. You would have to find a way to bind the slider using on() instead of each. The slider behavior is activated before the slider div exists. You have to bind it in a way that it is activated when the slider div is created.

Comment: Yes, i do a window.load() which load the slider,
and then I create the slider div so it don't works.

When you say "You would have to find a way to bind the slider using on() instead of each", so I should do the jquery after created the div, it's true?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to John Fable I have change  this:

- before I loaded the slider at the loading of my page:

  $(window).load(function() {
     $('#main-slider').flexslider();
  });
- and now, I load the slider in my javascript function:

  function toto() {
     // ...
      $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#main-slider').flexslider();
      });
    // ...
    }

  ...and it's working :)